# Where to find "-o" ("--output") argument in Clang/LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a custom LLVM analysis pass and want to output a simple CSV file in the pass's `do_finalization` method. I'd like to name the CSV file based on the desired output filename passed to Clang/LLVM, but I can't find this value.

For example, if I compile with:

`clang -o test test.c`

I'd like to output `test.csv` (or more generally `<output filename>.csv`). Where do I find the value `test`?

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in 
lib/TableGen/Main.cpp

```
static cl::opt<std::string>
OutputFilename("o", cl::desc("Output filename"), 
cl::value_desc("filename"),
               cl::init("-"));
```

You can define a command option in your analysis pass, and take the value as the output file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cl::getRegisteredOptions`](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#the-cl-getregisteredoptions-function) to grab a `cl::Option*` pointer and downcast it to the type the option is declared with:

```
std::string &OutputFilename () {
  auto *option = static_cast<llvm::cl::opt<std::string>*>(
    llvm::cl::getRegisteredOptions().lookup("o"));

  return option->getValue();
}
```

This will return the value of `-o` specified on the command line or `"-"` if the standard output is used.

The usual precautions about type-unsafety apply.

Comment: I'll test this later today; if it works, I'll accept. Thank you!